# RTW NMake U1077 error just by changing RTW>Custom Code>Source Code

Tags: simulink, nmake

The problem is I am trying to break the code out into a separate file and calling into it with an #include.

The source code works fine, but when I copy it all to a file (say foo.h) and replace the code in the text box with

```
#include "foo.h"
```

and add its path to the Custom Code>Include directories section, I get a failure to compile:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' 
Stop.
```

Most posts online suggest this means it can't find the compiler or is finding the wrong compiler, but it seems this is caused by aq change to the source code...

What is causing my issues?

**Edit:**

- MATLAB 2010b (x64)
- Simulink 7.6
- RTW 7.6
- RTW Embedded Coder 5.6
- MS VC++ Express 2008

Comment: If you build at command line using generated make file does that work?

Comment: The issue was simple and as always, unexpected RTW awesomeness. Essentially because I did not use a carriage return after `#include "foo.h"` it wrote the main cpp file with the following line pasted to the end of it. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a comment. See: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP Wrote:

> The issue was simple and as always, unexpected RTW awesomeness. Essentially because I did not use a carriage return after `#include "foo.h"` it wrote the main cpp file with the following line pasted to the end of it. Lesson learned.